# C++ Game Engine Book/Tutorial/Anything recent?

Tags: education

Before I get flamed, please understand that I have been looking for a while now. Yes, I have found a good amount of game engine tutorials...except filled with errors, out of date syntax, missing crucial information, and so on. Is there anywhere with a *recent* tutorial, or a book, anything at all?

I'm not asking for an opinion in graphics API's, just a point in the right direction to get started on game engine development.

I just want to make it clear, I have googled/stac5ked like crazy.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How exactly has a C++ book "out of date syntax"? The language didn't change for years...

Comment: @bummzack maybe he's refering to [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)

Comment: It did, actually, @bummzack. Also, you will not get flamed here. We are looking for quality questions that **can be answered** with a concrete, definitive and correct answer, something which your question is, I'm afraid, not.

Comment: That was a digression that referred to opengl in particular, and I do apologize that I left it it out. Besides, someone left a book I will by below.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry for the lack of info provided.

Answer (score 2):

This might not look like an answer but from my own experience - no, I haven't seen any tutorial or book on the subject that is worth mentioning.

I started learning it by making a game. When I built my second engine, I started by just picking any book on the subject and trying to reimplement things. I found lots of problems with the ways things were done according to the book on the way and if you want to follow any book, I suspect you will find just as many. So if possible, I'd suggest you avoid all of them as pure examples of design and let your work shape your engine as you improve it while making a game.

This doesn't mean you shouldn't read them and think about the things written. It's just that no book will be even 50% right about things and it's what you should keep in mind while you read them.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [Game Coding Complete](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133776574) to be a very good game / game engine programming book. It has up-to-date C++11 syntax along with some bits about C# and Lua for scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I own C4 Engine license and new book was for C4 Engine was recently released on Amazon

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginners-Guide-Engine-Second-Edition/dp/0985811714](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0985811714)

C4 Engine is developed Eric Lengyel
He is author of following book about 3D Games and Math
http://www.amazon.com/Eric-Lengyel/e/B001K8753Q/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1

C4 Engine comes with full source code for only $250

IMO It is very good deal.